# Clustered index update, how changing the index only at different column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan

I've table, 
example as

```
Id int primary key(clustered index)
Name varchar(255)not null (non-clustered index)
..
..
Other columns
```

I execute stored procedur as

```
update table1 set table1.Name=isnull(@Name,table1.Name) ,( updating other columns) where Id=@Id;
```

many times Name equals @Name;
In execution plan i saw [image]

if i change stored procedure as

```
update table1 set ( updating other columns) where Id=@Id;
```

i saw Cost:15%

### Question:

I need to change this procuder for two situation when

1. table1.Name= @Name
2. table1.Name <> Name.

In first case table1.Name doesn't change value or index doesn't update and clustered index update cost 15%;

in second case table1.Name changes value and clustered index update cost 50%.

#### Why index is updating when update a equal value?

i can't select "Name" and compare befor updatings

I know that create varchar column  index isn't good idea

### Update

update query **with** change Name column(execution CPU time **200ms**)
[image]

update query **without** change Name column(execution CPU time **70ms**)
[image]

### Update

#### Question is closed

Comment: there is no update operation in fact - it is equal to removing row and inserting new one physically; server will 'update' all rows you filtered; if you need to avoid matching rows to be affected - use WHERE to exclude those rows (table1.Name<>@Name);

Comment: @revoua ok, why "clustered index update" cost changed whan i remove table1.Name updating?

Comment: you can see all details in estimate and actual rows updated, share details

Comment: @revoua What details?

Comment: what's the whole execution plan? I'm betting there is a index key lookup

Comment: @scsimon   in update full execution plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fix my issue, I created a triger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_BeforeUpdateSubject] 
   ON  [dbo].[Subject] 
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @old_val  nvarchar(255),@new_val nvarchar(255) ;
        select
@old_val=[Name]   
from deleted;
select 
@new_val=[Name]
from inserted;
     if (@old_val=@new_val)  
    BEGIN

        UPDATE 
            Subject
        SET
            set new values for other colums,
            Subject.DLC             =   GETDATE()
        FROM 
            inserted
        WHERE
            Subject.Id = inserted.Id            
    END ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE 
            Subject
        SET
            Subject.Name = inserted.Name,
            set new values for other colums,
            Subject.DLC             =   GETDATE()
        FROM 
            inserted
        WHERE
            Subject.Id = inserted.Id                
    END

END
```

It's work perfect. Average value for update query is 90ms(CPU), old value 200ms